# Redux - Is it ok to pass props to child container components?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am running into a situation where I am having to pass in props from the parent container component to the child container components so that the presentational components within the child container have an initial state. Is there another way of approaching this? Is this frowned upon?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Why do the child components need an "initial state" from props?  Why does it depend on whether these props come from the parent context or redux?

Comment: I have some data being passed down to the parent container component from the rails server. I need to pass down this data to the child container components and in turn to the dumb views. Do I just dispatch an action with the sent in props and update the initial redux state? However, even then I'll have to pass it down to the child container.

Comment: I take the last statement back, if I do update it as part of the redux state I don't have to pass it down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the data in the Parent Container (the data you say is "from rails") being consumed by Redux?  If not, then that is your real problem.  Redux should be the one and only source of information for the react containers.  Redux, in turn, should accept information from the Rails app and store that information within it's global state.

Once you've achieved this, you now have a single source of truth for all information feeding into the React Containers.

If a sub-component needs any information at all, it should receive them from the parent-container's redux state information.

It is ok to have nested sub-components.  Simply continue to pass down information from 1 layer to the next.  E.g. ContainerA, which receives `name` from redux, can render ComponentX with `name={this.props.name}` and ComponentX can then render ComponentY with `name={this.props.name}` again.  This results in ComponentY being passed the information from Redux, through the parent component and container.

Your app should, naturally, have far more components than containers.  That's a good thing.  Components are inherently re-usable since they are only tied to a data *shape* rather than a data *source*.  Use containers sparingly, and only when you want to insert specific information into a series of components.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. When you say,  `ContainerA, which receives name from redux` do you mean receive it via the `getState()`? I might be missing something but I am under the impression that `mapStateFromProps` will only get triggered only when an action is dispatched.

Comment: You should use the `mapStateFromProps`, not manually from `getState`.  You are right that this only triggers on a dispatch, which in turn means that you should consume the rails information through a dispatch to store it in Redux.  Depending on how you are retrieving it from rails will determine how you do so, but the goal should be to route everything through the same data flow, which means all incoming data should cause a redux dispatch.